# The meaning of Eden?

Tags: hebrew, eden

I have heard that Eden in Hebrew means "presence" and not specifically a place.  The word is made of five strokes each with a meaning of its own.  They are: Spot, Moment, Presence, Open Door, Delightful. I lack the Hebrew skills to confirm or reject this linguistic understanding.  Is this a fair and accurate expression of the Hebrew Eden?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Garden = ga-rden = ga-rhedon = rheden = עֵ֔דֶן = eden

Answer (score 1):

Eden עֵ֔דֶן [Genesis 2] derives from עֵ֔ד "Witness" in regards to their visual delight.

The Klein Dictionary defines עֵ֔דֶן "Eden" as : pleasure, delight, luxury. -- עֵ֔דֶן Eden (name of the region in which lies the Paradise. [The name is usually explained as ‘the place of delight’] -- M. D. Cassuto explains the name Eden — with reference to the meaning of the base ‘dn in Ugaritic — as a place that is ‘well watered throughout’.]

[https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_עֵֽדֶן_ᴵᴵ.1?ven=Carta_Jerusalem%3B_1st_edition,_1987&lang=bi](https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%A2%D6%B5%D6%BD%D7%93%D6%B6%D7%9F_%E1%B4%B5%E1%B4%B5.1?ven=Carta_Jerusalem%3B_1st_edition,_1987&lang=bi)